# Comparing time between 2 lists in Django Template

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates, django-views

I know there is something probably wrong with the logic and I have been working on this for some time and can't think straight right now and could really use some help.

I am basically trying to print out a list of events of any given day in my Django template. The problem I am running into is when I have multiple events on any given day. The `time_slots` that has an event (which is coming in from `my_workouts`) prints out the `book button` as well on it's second or third run through the loop.

```
{% for slot in time_slots %}
  {{ slot.time }}
  {% for event in my_workouts %}
    {% ifchanged %}
      {% if event.start_time <= slot.time and event.end_time > slot.time %}
        EventExists 
      {% else %}
        <button type="button" class="btn">Book</button>
      {% endif %} 
    {% endifchanged %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It currently prints out as...

```
09:00 EventExists [Book] 
10:00 [Book]
11:00 [Book]
12:00 [Book] EventExists
```

I would like it to print as...

```
09:00 EventExists 
10:00 [Book]
11:00 [Book]
12:00 EventExists
```

Comment: You should move the logic into the view, not into template. Do all of that in Python, then just render. How do you need it to be shown? Time for each event?

Comment: It would help to see some more data.  What does my_workouts contain?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov I have an example in my post on how I want it to be shown. Basically show if an hr time slot is full and if it's not... i want to show a book button

Comment: @Carl my_workouts contains a list of objects for the event that has already been booked on that day and time_slots contains a list of time from 09:00 to 17:00 .... i want to basically match the time between the 2 and show if that time_slot is full or empty

Comment: So you want to show `EventExists` even if there could be `[Book]` for the same time? Right?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov if `EventExists` for a certain time_slot ... there should NOT be a `[Book]` in the same time_slot.... so there should only be one of them showing up per time_slot

Answer (score 0):

in your view.py:

```
for ev in events:
   ev.IsEvetExits = False
   if ((event.start_time <= slot.time) and (event.end_time > slot.time)): 
      ev.IsEventExits =  True
```

Then in your template write:

```
    {% for slot in time_slots %}
     {{ slot.time }}
       {% for event in my_workouts %}
         {% ifchanged %}
           {% if Event.IsEventExits %}
        EventExists 
        {% else %}
        <button type="button" class="btn">Book</button>
      {% endif %} 
    {% endifchanged %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```